# subquery replace value wrapped in list in collaction A for key in collection B mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a query question with mongodb

There are 2 collections in my database, names `status` and `menu`

The primary key in `status` `_id` is the foreign key for the value of the bought list in `menu` collection

For `status` collection:

```
{
    "_id": "green", "description": "running"
}
{
    "_id": "yellow", "description": "prepareing"
}
{
    "_id": "black", "description": "closing"
}
{
    "_id": "red", "description": "repairing"
}
```

For `menu` collection:

```
{
    "name": "tony",
    "bought": [
        {
            "notebook": "green"
        },
        {
            "cellphone": "red"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "name": "andy",
    "bought": [
        {
            "fan": "black"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I query to get the following answer?

(Just replace `description` for `_id`)

```
{
    "name": "tony",
    "bought": [
        {
            "notebook": "running"
        },
        {
            "cellphone": "repairing"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it a subquery issue for NoSQL? How can I use the key word to google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version using aggregate:

We start with a [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage to extract each bought in a separate row

Then a [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to normalize the bought field.

We can then perform a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join on status.

Then we use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to regroup by name

And [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to reset bought to denormalized style

```
> db.menu.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a102b0b49b317e3f8d6268b"), "name" : "tony", "bought" : [ { "notebook" : "green" }, { "cellphone" : "red" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a102b0b49b317e3f8d6268c"), "name" : "andy", "bought" : [ { "fan" : "black" } ] }
> db.status.find()
{ "_id" : "green", "description" : "running" }
{ "_id" : "yellow", "description" : "prepareing" }
{ "_id" : "black", "description" : "closing" }
{ "_id" : "red", "description" : "repairing" }
> db.menu.aggregate([
{$unwind: '$bought'}, 
{$project: {name: 1, bought: {$objectToArray: '$bought'}}}, {$unwind: '$bought'}, 
{$lookup: {from: 'status', localField: 'bought.v', foreignField: '_id', as: "status"}}, 
{$project: {name: 1, bought: ["$bought.k", { $arrayElemAt: ["$status.description", 0]}]}}, 
{$addFields: {b: {v: {$arrayElemAt: ['$bought', 1]}, k: { $arrayElemAt: ['$bought', 0]}}}}, 
{$group: {_id: { name: '$name', _id: "$_id"}, b: {$push: "$b"}}},     
{$project: {_id: "$_id._id", name: "$_id.name", bought: {$arrayToObject: "$b"}}}
])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a102b0b49b317e3f8d6268c"), "name" : "andy", "bought" : { "fan" : "closing" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a102b0b49b317e3f8d6268b"), "name" : "tony", "bought" : { "notebook" : "running", "cellphone" : "repairing" } }
```

I think it can be performed in a simplier way, but I don't know how (and I would be glad to know).

Comment: Thanks! It useful for me. And I also want to know a more simplier answer.